# How to render rest api call in node.js with express and handlebar or other template engine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

### Use case

Using Node.js, Express and a template engine like Handlebars to query rest APIs like Wordpress and CouchDB and render the results.

### I have come that far

```
var https = require('https');

var express = require('express');
var handlebars = require('express-handlebars')
        .create({ defaultLayout:'main' });

var app = express();
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('ip', process.env.IP);

var options = {
  hostname: 'public-api.wordpress.com',
  path: '/rest/v1.1/sites/somesite.wordpress.com/posts/16',
  method: 'GET'
};

app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  https.request(options, function(restRes) {
    console.log('STATUS: ' + restRes.statusCode);
    res.render('home', { "title": "Test" }); // This code works.
    restRes.on('data', function (jsonResult) {
//      res.render('home', { "title": "Test" }); This code (after removing the line above) does not work.
      console.log('BODY: ' + jsonResult);
    });
  }).end();
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), app.get('ip'), function(){
  console.log( 'Express started on http://' + app.get('ip') + ": " +
    app.get('port') + '; press Ctrl-C to terminate.' );
});
```

This code works and the jsonResult show correcty at the console. Moving the line `res.render('home', { "title": "Test" });` inside the `restRes.on('data', function (jsonResult)` callback throws an error.

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:331:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:718:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:163:12)
    at res.render.done (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:957:10)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express-handlebars/lib/utils.js:26:13)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:374:17)
```

Do I oversee an obvious error? How to do this the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory, that is you cannot set header when response is already sent. The error could happen due to the following

**Cause 1**

The following fails because you try to send response more than once.

```
//the following lines send the response 
res.render('home', { "title": "Test" }); // This code works. 

restRes.on('data', function (jsonResult) {
//you have already send the response above, hence the error
res.render('home', { "title": "Test" }); This code (after removing the line above) does not work.
  console.log('BODY: ' + jsonResult);
});
```

**Cause 2**

This fails and shows the error because, the `.on('data')` is called more than once (depending on size of response) and that is because the data is returned in chunks hence, you are trying to `res.render` multiple times.

```
restRes.on('data', function (jsonResult) {
   res.render('home', { "title": "Test" }); 
   console.log('BODY: ' + jsonResult);
});
```

**Possible Solution**

You need to use the `.on('data')` to receive the chunks and build the entire response here and then use `.on('end')` to do `res.render` with the complete response. Something as follow:

```
var body = '';
//use the chunks to build the whole response into body variable
restRes.on('data', function (chunk) {
   body += chunk; 
});

//this is called when the request is finished and response is returned
//hence, use the constructed body string to parse it to json and return
restRes.on('end', function () {
   console.log('whole response > ' + body); 
   var jsonObject = JSON.parse(body);
   res.render('home', {data:jsonObject}); 
   //in your view use the data that is json object.
});
```

**Another possible solution** 
Rather than concatenating the chunks returned to `.on('data')`, you can push them in an array and then in `.on('end')` to join the array elements which would construct the response body and then parse it to JSON and then return it. Sample below:

```
var body = [];
restRes.on('data', function(chunk) {
  body.push(chunk);
});

restRes.on('end', function() {
  //joined the chunks 
  var result = JSON.parse(data.join(''))
  res.render('home', {data: result}); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks Raf. Everything works fine now. Just a small additional question. I do not find/understand the corresonding doc. [Node.js v5.5.0 Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) does not name the 'data' event. Where do I find the doc?

Comment: Except for this bit https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest I also could not find anything about this in Node.js docs. I answered your question using my previous experience with **Can't set header ...**. You might be able to google and find tutorial on how does Node.js Request work.

Comment: Yes, "Google" say something about this but still feeling uncomfortable not finding this 'data' and 'end' events documented in the Node.js docs.

Comment: In the case, someone cares: `https.request(options, function(restRes)`. The [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) are saying "The optional callback parameter will be added as a one time listener for the 'response' event". The [response argument](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_response) is a [http.IncomingMessage](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage) which implements [ReadableStream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) where the events  'data' and 'end' are explained.